# How can i set openApi generator global properites in build.gradle.kts

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, openapi-generator

I am having trouble setting global properties in build.gradle.kts
Example presented in open api generator plugin looks like this

```
openApiGenerate {
// other settings omitted
    globalProperties = [
        modelDocs: "false",
        apis: "false"
    ]
}
```

Above code is supposed to be used in build.gradle. I am trying to put it in build.gradle.kts file with no luck so far. I am using org.openapi.generator 4.3.1 plugin. How can i convert it to kotlin?

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```kotlin
openApiGenerate {
    globalProperties.set(
        mapOf(
            "apis" to "false",
            "models" to "false"
        )
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved it using:

```kotlin
openApiGenerate {
    generatorName.set("kotlin")
    inputSpec.set("$projectDir/src/main/resources/api-docs-v3.json")
    outputDir.set("$buildDir/generated")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered that globalProperties should be replaced with system properties in new version of gradle
Here is solution:

```
openApiGenerate {
    systemProperties.put("models", "")
}
```

Comment: +1 for the setter methods on the properties.  I don't know if this is the best approach or not.  Still confused on why the Kotlin DSL doesn't seem to want to play 'normal syntax' with the OpenAPI Generator plugin.